# Analyzing .java files from shell

Tags: java, bash, shell, code-analysis

I want to write a script that will generate a graph of interfaces, abstract classes and implementation classes.

As far as producing the graph, my intention is to use GraphViz to produce the output, and I'd like to be able to make a directed graph with different node colors for interfaces, abstract classes and implementation classes. Once I am able to scan all the java files, making the graph shouldn't be hard.

In order to accomplish this though, I need to write a bunch of piped grep commands, awk, sed, etc. My question is, is there a utility I can use to scan all java files and give me an output of:

- Abstract Classes (Mandatory)
- Implementation Classes (Mandatory)
- Interfaces (Mandatory)
- Usages of other classes in file [ie, member variables, etc] (Optional)

Comment: Why do you need to use bash, instead of java?

Comment: Just because I'd prefer to keep it a shell script, but if there's a viable option for using Java I'd love to hear it regardless

Comment: With libraries like _Reflections_ is easy

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely do not want to use Bash for this. Java has a specific - and [complex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) - syntax, which will be a nightmare to parse with regular expressions. You should instead look into tools that parse Java's [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), or even just look for existing Java source visualizers - there are a number of them.